# Truly Random Unit Tests in Junit

Tags: junit5

Is there a way to run truly random unit tests in JUnit? I want to do a bunch of test runs with my tests in truly random order to try to detect test pollution. It seems like the best I can do is put @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.Random.class) at the class levels, but classes can still unfortunately share variables.

Answer (score 2):

On test class level you can indeed randomize the executing of your tests using `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.Random.class)`.

The default behavior of JUnit 5 also ensures to create a **new instance** of your test class for **each test method**, so I guess

> ... but classes can still, unfortunately, share variable

Shouldn't be a problem here.

That would randomize the test execution order of your tests inside a class, but as far as I know there is currently no way to set the order of which test classes are picked when. There is an [on-going discussion](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1948) for this on GitHub.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be correct. I put a breakpoint into the test and a variable is shared. It's also shared across classes.The variable is created in a centralized test utils class.

Comment: That might be true, but with the information you provided in your question, it's hard to guess your test setup. Please add a sample test with the whole test hierarchy and all involved classes.